# Python string to raw string for regex comparison

Tags: python, string, python-re

I am looking for a way to convert a string I am passed into a raw string for re search.

---

For my experimentation I am using the following regex query `^\/\.\t\\`  against the following string `/. \` .

Also, I will be referring to how python interprets the string at runtime as the *actual string*.

---

I am retrieving the above regex query from a json file that is provided to me, when I dump that json into a dict the regex is passed as a string not a raw string (I know they are both of type 'str', but they get encoded differently).

But, the string `'^\/\.\t\\ '` is equal to  the *actual string* `'^\\/\\.\t\\'`.
Obviously in this case the re compiler reads the `\t` in that *actual string* as a literal tab character, this breaks the re search.

Now, if I use the raw string `r'^\/\.\t\\ '` it equates to  the *actual string* `'^\\/\\.\\t\\\\'`.
This string works perfectly when the re search is preformed.

So, I have been looking for a way to convert an existing string into a raw string.  But I don't believe it is actually possible to convert a string like this.

Though I have tried the following with no luck:

```
"%r" %query == "'^\\\\/\\\\.\\t\\\\'"

r"%s" %query == '^\\/\\.\t\\'

ast.literal_eval('r"'+ query +'"') == "'^\\\\/\\\\.\\t\\\\'"

query.encode("unicode-escape").decode() == '^\\\\/\\\\.\\t\\\\'

query.replace('\\','\\\\') == '^\\\\/\\\\.\t\\\\'
```

---

I have also looked into using an *object_hook* on the `json.load`, but after investigation it seems it creates the dictionary and then you can just modify those existing elements.  This just led me back to the same problem as above.

---

I created a repl.it to experiment with the problem here: [repl.it link](https://repl.it/repls/ReliableHeavenlyMachinecodeinstruction)

---

Honestly, at this point I am all out of ideas and don't know what else to even try. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `r` indicates a raw string **literal**. But raw string literals and normal string literals all just become strings when your program is executed. You can't convert to something that only exists in source code.